# Get object names from a array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

i cannot find a solution of my issue. i probably making things more complicated.

here is the array:

```
var Statistics = {
"STAT 1 COLUMNS" : ["Date","Group Name","Product Name","Version","Version Date","Status","Total","Total L0","Total L1","Total L2","To be validated","Created","Updated"],
"STAT 2 TITLE" : ["12/12/2013","Led Zeppelin","roofies","V5.3","2013-08-13 ","ACCEPTED <br/>(2013-9-10)","774","334","3","437","20","57","102"],
"STAT 3 TITLE" : ["22/11/2014","Deep Purple","upper","V1","2006-01-01 "," ","3","1","0","2","1"," "," "],
...
}
```

i would like to get the object name (such as 'STAT 1 COLUMNS', 'STAT 2 TITLE', 'STAT 3 TITLE'..) for a specific object, by specifing the index.

for instance, *givemepleasethenameoftheobject('2') -> "STAT 3 TITLE"*

can you please give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the members of an object like this:

```
for (var key in Statistics) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

However, you *can not* reliably access them by index like that. The members in an object is not guaranteed to remain in the same order that you create them, and different browsers actually do order the members differently.

If you want to access the member names by index in a predictable way, you would need to get all names and then sort them:

```
function givemepleasethenameoftheobject(index) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in Statistics) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
  keys.sort();
  return keys[index];
}
```

If you don't need to be compatible with older browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer 8), you can use the [`Object.Keys` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
function givemepleasethenameoftheobject(index) {
  var keys = Object.keys(Statistics);
  keys.sort();
  return keys[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
function givemepleasethenameoftheobject(index, data) {
  var i = 0;
  for ( var k in data ) {
    if ( index == i++ ) {
      return k;
    }
  }
}

var result = givemepleasethenameoftheobject(2, Statistics);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you need:

```
function getStatisticName(index)
{
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in Statistics)
    {
        if(count == index)
            return i;

        count++;
    }
}
```

See this [<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/TcuvG/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'Object.keys();' function.

```
Object.keys(Statistics); // ['STAT 1 COLUMNS', 'STAT 2 TITLE', 'STAT 3 TITLE'];
```

Comment: As pawel noted in hes/her answer, the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Object keys order is not guaranteed in JavaScript, so `gimmeTheKey(Statistics, 2)` is *not guaranteed* to return `"STAT 3 TITLE"`.

However:

```
function gimmeTheKey( obj, idx ){
    return Object.keys( obj )[idx];
}
```